# Getting a new accesstoken

Tags: php

I am trying to retrieve a new access token with my refresh token. Before I run a script to retrieve a new access token I want to check if my access token is still valid.

I am trying to do this with exceptions:

```
try
{
    // Connect
    $session = new SoapClient("../webservices/session.asmx?wsdl", array('trace' => 1));
    $result = $session->AccessTokenLogon($accessTokenparams);
}

catch (SoapFault $e)
{
    // Check if AcccessToken returns TokenInvalid
    if ($result->AccessTokenLogonResult == "TokenInvalid")
    {
        // AccessToken is not valid anymore
        // ..
        // Run script to get new access token
        // ..
        // $_SESSION["access_token"] = $access_token;


    }
    else
    {
        // AccessToken is valid
        echo "AccessToken is valid";
    }
}

finally
{
    // Run script with valid AccessToken
    global $result, $session;

    $cluster = $result->cluster;
    $qq = new domDocument();
    $qq->loadXML($session->__getLastResponse());
    $newurl = $cluster . '/webservices/processxml.asmx?wsdl';
    try
    {
        $client = new SoapClient($newurl);
        $header = new SoapHeader('http://www.website.com/', 'Header', array('AccessToken' =>$_SESSION["access_token"]));
    }
    catch (SoapFault $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    try
    {
        echo '<br /><br />XML Result:<br /><br />';
        $xml = ""; // XML request
        $result = $client->__soapCall('ProcessXmlString', array(array('xmlRequest'=>$xml)), null, $header);

    }
    catch (SoapFault $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

With a valid access token the script is working. The XML request is posted to the webservice.

The script is not working when the accesstoken is not valid anymore. The script stores the new accesstoken in the session: `$_SESSION["access_token"] = $access_token;` but is not running the 'finally' part after retrieving a new accesstoken.

Does someone know how I can fix this and run the 'finally' after retrieving a new accesstoken?

Comment: What is the purpose of the token ? Can you make a demo of the issue ?

Comment: _“but is not running the 'finally' part”_ - have you actually _verified_ that it doesn’t go into that block? Or are you perhaps drawing a wrong conclusion from not getting the result you were expecting?